# Bootstrap three column divs middle elastic

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: 3 column divs]

I'm trying to achieve bootstrap three columns divs, *look at the previous image*, where:

- div 1: width is corresponding to its content pushed to the left
- div 2: is as wide as possible
- div 3: width is corresponding to its content pushed to the right

I can't get this to work without losing the horizontal alignment. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the code you have in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the full layout it is difficult to answer fully but try this as a starting point

```
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 pull-left" style="background-color:red">Left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10" style="background-color:green">Middle</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 pull-right" style="background-color:blue">Right</div>
</div>
```

Ignore the style elements in final code. That's just there to make it visible.

The point being the pull-left and pull-right in the outer columns cobined with the middle item making up the 12 columns.

Hope that helps.

Dave